# Show on my select result that don't match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these three tables:

campaigns

```
 id |    name     | campaign_strategy_id 
----+-------------+----------------------
  5 | Teste Diego |                    3
```

campaign_strategy_blocked_routes

```
 campaign_strategy_id | route_id 
----------------------+----------
                    3 |        2
                    3 |        6
```

And routes:

```
      name       | id 
-----------------+----
 Vonex Teste     |  3
 Filial Total IP |  2
 Filial TotalIP  |  6
 Tellfree teste  |  5
```

And i need to check the routes that arent blocked on a campaign. In that case, note that campaign id 5 have two blocked routes: 2 and 6, but I need to show the other two routes on my select: 3 and 5.

I have something like this:

```
select campaigns.name, routes.id as route_id from campaigns left join campaign_strategy_blocked_routes on campaigns.campaign_strategy_id = campaign_strategy_blocked_routes.campaign_strategy_id left join routes on campaign_strategy_blocked_routes.route_id = routes.id
```

But the result, obviously is:

```
    name     | route_id 
-------------+----------
 Teste Diego |        2
 Teste Diego |        6
```

And, like i said, what i need is:

```
    name     | route_id 
-------------+----------
 Teste Diego |        3
 Teste Diego |        5
```

Is it possible to do this?

Basically, who wants to play: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1305/3

Comment: Do you have a primary key that identifies the Campaign ID and Route ID? If not, your best bet would be to create a primary key, maybe by concatenating those two fields, and get it to match them up that way

Comment: Hi jswan. I dont have association on campaigns and routes, only campaigns -> campaign_strategy_blocked_routes -> routes, and i cant create a pk on these tables too :(

Comment: I don't know how this can be done.  You are looking for records that don't exist in `campaign_strategy_blocked_routes`, but your relationship between the other 2 tables (`campaigns` and `routes`) are in `campaign_strategy_blocked_routes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.name, r.id
from campaigns c 
inner join routes r 
on not exists(select 1 from campaign_strategy_blocked_routes 
                where route_id = r.id 
                and campaign_strategy_id = c.campaign_strategy_id)
```

**Explanation:**

Rows from `campaigns` table and `routes` table are joined if the subquery doesn't find any matching rows from `campaign_strategy_blocked_routes` table.

`exists` returns `true` if one or more matching rows from `campaign_strategy_blocked_routes` are found, but since we care about the case where there is no match we negate the expression (i.e `not exists(...)`).

The subquery is essentially equivalent to

```
select 1
from campaigns c 
inner join campaign_strategy_blocked_routes csbr
    on csbr.campaign_strategy_id = c.campaign_strategy_id
inner join routes r on csbr.route_id = r.id
```

So it finds blocked routes for campaigns.
But instead of joining tables in the subquery the values `r.id` and `c.campaign_strategy_id` are provided as constants by the outer query.

And `select 1` is used because we don't care about returning any particular data from the subquery, we just want to know if there are any rows to return.

[Documentation about `exists`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)

Comment: It worked fine, thanks! Could you explain me in details the subquery inside the parentheses?

Comment: @RaphaelTelatim, I updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, where do you see the mistake? See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1a469/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name, c.id AS route_id from campaigns a, campaign_strategy_blocked_routes b
FULL OUTER JOIN routes c
ON b.route_id = c.id
WHERE b.route_id is null
OR c.id is null
```

Returns:

```
name         route_id
Teste Diego  3
Teste Diego  5
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather tricky and requires tricky solution. Something like this.

```
--tables
declare @campaigns table(id int,    name varchar(20), campaign_strategy_id int)
insert @campaigns values ( 5, 'Teste Diego', 3),
( 6, 'Test 2', 4) --I added an extra test row

declare @campaign_strategy_blocked_routes table(id int,route_id int)
insert @campaign_strategy_blocked_routes values(3,2),(3,6),
(4,3) --extra test

declare @routes table(name varchar(10),id int)
insert @routes values ('a',3), ('a',2), ('a',6), ('a',5) --names are not used

select distinct c.name,t.route_id
from @campaigns c 
left join @campaign_strategy_blocked_routes x1 on c.campaign_strategy_id=x1.id
--here is the trick. non-existing rows
--cross apply -- MS SQL Server
left join lateral --PostgreSQL
(select id
from @routes r --all routes
except
--used routes
select route_id
from @campaign_strategy_blocked_routes x
where x.id=x1.id
) t(route_id)
on true -- PostgreSQL only
order by c.name

--Results
name          route_id
Test 2        2
Test 2        5
Test 2        6
Teste Diego   3
Teste Diego   5
```

Comment: Got "syntax error" when execute: select distinct c.name, t.route_id from campaigns c inner join campaign_strategy_blocked_routes x1 on c.campaign_strategy_id=x1.id cross apply (select id from routes r except select route_id from campaign_strategy_blocked_routes x where x.id=x1.id ) t(route_id) order by c.name;